# How to make Inset graphics maintain relative sizes when combined

Tags: graphics

I am learning a little about Inset, but after trying all options, I can't get this to work. I need to inset separately made `Graphics2D` objects, into one  main `Graphics2D` but have them show up there with same relative sizes they had on their own. I use the Axes of the main Graphics as measuring stick yard to check that this is true.

For example, if I make disk of radius 1, and rectangle of width 6, and then Inset them to main Graphics, I expect them to show there with same relative sizes. Disk will still have radius 1 and the rectangle will still have width 6, but now when looking at the main Axes.

Here is an example:

```
 g1 = Graphics[{LightGray, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

.ps the plot above is same code, but added `Axes->True` to it for illustration. I do not  use `Axes` in the separate Graphics. But use Axes in the main Graphics.

```
 g2 = Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Blue, Rectangle[{-3, -1}, {3, 1}]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I want to insert the disk at origin of main Graphics, and insert the rectangle at location `(2,2)`. But this is what happens when I do

```
Graphics[
 {Inset[g1, {0, 0}],
  Inset[g2, {2, 2}]
  }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4, 4}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looking at the above, the disk now shows with radius 2, and the rectangle became square. (relative the Axes of the main graphics). What I'd like to get is this: (did this manually, by adjusting the image sizes one by one after inserting)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried many options, but can't get the effect I want. Tried Scaled and changing aspect ratio setting, but did  not help.

What is the correct way to inset graphics, so they show up with same axes limits/sizes as in the original graphics? but now will be relative to the main Graphics.

Comment: Strangely when I try to reproduce your code my rectangle do not become a square but  stays a rectangle (with its correct aspect ratio.) (OSX10.9.5, v10.0.2)

Comment: In your graphic, the final disk radius is not 2 but 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
Graphics[
  MapThread[
    Inset[##, {0, 0}, #2 - # & @@ First@PlotRange@#] &,
    {{g1, g2}, {{0, 0}, {2, 2}}}
  ],
  Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4, 4}}
]
```

[image]

For precision I believe one will need to set `PlotRangePadding -> 0` and `ImagePadding -> 0` in each of the inset `Graphics`.

Comment: thanks, but this is not really what I meant. You just used the `g1` axes instead of the `master` graphics axes I want to combine many graphics into. May be my example was too simple. I'll add `g2` to make it more clear what I mean. i.e. I'll have Disk and Rectangle, each separate graphics2D, then want to combine them into one Graphics, using Inset, and have them come out with same relative sizes as each originally. Will update my question soon to make this clear. in few minutes...

Comment: @Nasser Looking forward to your update...

Comment: @Nasser I took another shot at this, hopefully with a bit more success.

Comment: thanks, yes, this is exactly what I wanted. You are right, `PlotRangePadding -> 0` is needed in the separate graphics for more accurate positioning. I'll test it with more graphics now as well.

Comment: Did not know that `PlotRange` can be used as a function (`PlotRange[somegraphics]`) ...  :) Any refs ?

Comment: @SquareOne I learned it from someone here, but my memory is not good enough to recall from whom.  I don't believe it is documented.  I'll *try* to remember to let you know if I find or recall anything else.

Answer (score 2):

```
g1 = Graphics[{LightGray, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
g2 = Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Blue, Rectangle[{-3, -1}, {3, 1}]}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];
F[t_] := Translate[#, t] &;
G[t_] := MapAt[F[t], {1}];

Show[g1, G[{2, 2}]@g2, Axes -> True]
```

Not using Inset, I could do this.

[image]

For more detail, you can refer my question :

[Parallel movement(Translation) of entire Graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286209/parallel-movementtranslation-of-entire-graphics)

Answer (score 0):

```
g1 = Graphics[{LightGray, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
g2 = Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .5}]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
Graphics[
{
 Inset[g1, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Scaled[{.35, 1}]],
 Inset[g2, {0, 2}, {0, 0}, Scaled[{.35, 1}]]
},
 Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4, 4}},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange.  Unfortunately this is not the result that Nasser desires; here both objects appear with the same width whereas the rectangle should be much wider.

Comment: ....Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .333}]}, .....
  Inset[g1, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Scaled[{.175, 1}]],
  Inset[g2, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}, Scaled[{.35 + .175, 1}]]
  .....