# Why does a Graphics combination with Insets persist to be larger than the actual graphics?

Tags: graphics

```
fadingPrimitive[size_, formula_, c_] :=
 DensityPlot[
  Max[0, formula],
  {x, -size, size}, {y, -size, size},
  ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, c] &),
  Frame -> False];

smoothlyFadingColorDisk[r_, c_] :=
 fadingPrimitive[r, r - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], c];

smoothlyFadingColorRing[rs_, rb_, c_] :=
 fadingPrimitive[rs + rb, rs - Abs[rb - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], c];
```

Up to this point everything works nice. The image size is exactly as large as the actual graphics:

```
smoothlyFadingColorDisk[1, Purple]
```

[image]

```
smoothlyFadingColorRing[0.25, 1.25, Blue]
```

[image]

But when I try to combine them, the image size suddenly gets much larger than the actual graphics:

```
Graphics[{
 Inset[smoothlyFadingColorDisk[1, Purple]],
 Inset[smoothlyFadingColorRing[0.25, 1.25, Blue]]}]
```

[image]

I tried `ImageSize->Scaled[1]`, `ImageSize->Full`, `ImageSize->All`, `ImageSize->Automatic` - all fail or even make the disproportion even greater.

```
Show[
 smoothlyFadingColorRing[0.25, 1.25, Blue],
 smoothlyFadingColorDisk[1, Purple]]
```

This works as expected, but I'd rather avoid show: I want to be able to use `Inset`s to be able to reposition the graphics, and it seems I can't use `Inset`s with `Show`.

Why does this happen? How to set this straight? Thanks in advance!

Comment: closely related: [73522](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73522/5478)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coordinate system of the enclosing `Graphics` is completely independent of the one used in the `Inset`. So you have to specify in `Inset` how it is to be positioned and sized relative to the enclosing `Graphics`. In your case, you just want to modify the size. That's the fourth argument in `Inset` (it's optional), so the code looks like this:

```
Graphics[{Inset[smoothlyFadingColorDisk[1, Purple], Automatic, 
   Automatic, Scaled[1]], 
  Inset[smoothlyFadingColorRing[0.25, 1.25, Blue], Automatic, 
   Automatic, Scaled[1]]}]
```

[image: shades]