# How to plot functions in multiple coordinate systems

Tags: plotting

I´m curious if is it possible to plot in:

A. two different Cartesian coordinate system who share the same plane but have different origins and rotation. The visualization should preferably resemble the output of the Plot function, but with two sets of axis.

B. as A. but the systems don't share the same plane and with the axis projected as in Plot3D.

This sketch shows an idea of what A would look like, though in a simplified way:

[image]

---

This sketch gives a 3D perspective view of an example of B:
[image]

The aim is to help visualizing the projection of a function, path or list from one coordinate system to another (parent) system. I am not familiar with the mathematical concepts dealing with projections, so being able to plot would be a great start.

Comment: The drawings are added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[showF]
showF[tr_: {10, 10}, rt_: {-Pi/4, {0, 0}}, 
    opts : OptionsPattern[{Graphics, Graphics3D}]][g_] := 
 Module[{head = Head[g], pr = PlotRange[g],
   transF=Composition[TranslationTransform[tr], RotationTransform[rt[[1]], rt[[2]]]]}, 
  Module[{prim = If[head === Graphics3D, Cuboid, Rectangle] @@Transpose[pr],
    points = Cases[Normal@g, (Line | Point | Tube)[x_, ___] :> x, Infinity][[1]],
    axes = Thread[{#, {##2}}, List, {2}] & @@ 
        Nearest[#, #[[1]], If[head === Graphics3D, 4, 3]] &@Tuples[pr], gr2}, 
   gr2 = {g[[1]], EdgeForm[Directive[GrayLevel[.4], AbsoluteThickness[.02]]], 
     FaceForm[], prim, Arrow /@ axes};
   head[{gr2, GeometricTransformation[gr2, transF], Red, Dashed, 
     Line /@ Transpose[{points, transF /@ points}]}, opts]]]
```

Examples:

```
gr = Graphics[{Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}, {7, 1}}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 7}}]; 
llp = ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}, {7,  1}}, 
    BaseStyle -> Thick, PlotRangePadding -> 0];
lp = ListPlot[RandomReal[3, 10], PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[.03], Orange]];

Row[showF[{10, 10}, {-Pi/4, {0, 0}}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 300] /@ {gr, llp, lp}]
```

[image]

```
grb = Graphics3D[Cases[gr,
   Line[x_, ___] :> Line[Insert[#, #2, 2] & @@@ Thread[{x, 0}]], Infinity],
  ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 2}, {0, 7}}]; 

showF[{5, 5, 5}, {Pi/4, {0, 1, 0}}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 400]@grb
```

[image]

```
tubes = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.7], CapForm["Butt"], 
   Tube[{{1, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 0}, {5, 5, 0}, {5, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 5}}, .25]}]; 

showF[{10, 5, 5}, {-Pi/4, {0, 1, 0}}]@tubes
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

```
gr = Graphics[{Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}, {7, 1}}]}]; 

Graphics[{gr2 = Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 1}, #}] & /@ ({#, Reverse@#2} & @@ 
                 PlotRange[gr]), gr[[1]]}][[1]], 
  GeometricTransformation[GeometricTransformation[gr2, RotationTransform[-45 Degree]],
   TranslationTransform[{10, 10}]]}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, define a function that does the required transformations given a graphics object as input:

```
ClearAll[gtF, showF]
gtF[tr_: {10, 10}, rt_: - Pi/4] := With[{transF = 
   Composition[TranslationTransform[tr], RotationTransform[rt]]}, 
   GeometricTransformation[#, transF]] &;

showF[tr_: {10, 10}, rt_: - Pi/4, opts : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] := 
  With[{gr2 = Graphics[{Arrow /@ ({{#, #2}, {#, #3}} & @@ 
            Tuples[PlotRange@#]), #[[1]]}][[1]]},
    Graphics[{gr2, gtF[tr, rt]@gr2}, opts]] &;

llp = ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}, {7, 1}},
        BaseStyle -> Thick];
Row[showF[{10, 10}, -Pi/4, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 300] /@ 
        {gr, llp, ListPlot[RandomReal[1, 20]]}]
```

[image]

Note: You can also use the function `gtF` with `MapAt` as follows:

```
Show[llp, MapAt[gtF[], FullGraphics@llp, {1}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a very meaty answer. Your first code snippet works. The second and third seems to ask for llp. Have I missed something ?

Comment: @MathLind, sorry i must have deleted it during the last update. I just added the missing line.

Comment: From your third code snippet I get an error message containing multiple instances of "Axes::axes: "{{False,False},{False,False}} is not a valid axis specification. " and "Ticks::ticks: "{Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification." Any idea what is going on ?

Comment: @MathLind, It could be version/os difference; it is working as expected in version 9.0.1.0 (windows 8 64-bit), I haven't test it on version 10. I will post  a version that doesn't depend on the function `boxF` later.

Comment: just to be sure... I am referring to the code snippet containing Show[llp, MapAt[gtF[], FullGraphics@llp, {1}], PlotRange -> All]

Comment: @MathLind, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you very much, kguler. While LLlAMnYP´s answer is very clear, simple and spot on, your answer adresses both 2- and 3D visualization. As always, a lot to learn from your code. I bet you are by far the most productive participant on SE, cheers :)

Comment: @MathLind, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach with `Inset`. From the documentation:

> `Inset[`*`obj,pos,opos,size,dirs`*`]`
>   represents an object `obj` inset in a graphic...
>   specifies that the inset should be placed at position `pos` in the graphic...
>   aligns the inset so that position `opos` in the object lies at position `pos` in the enclosing graphic...
>   specifies the `size` of the inset in the coordinate system of the enclosing graphic...
>   specifies that the axes of the inset should be oriented in directions `dirs`.

Thus with this line of code

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1.5, 5}}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], {3, 3.5}, {0, 0}, 5, {1, -1/3}]]
```

we get this plot:

[image]

Comment: I was about to post this too. +1 If the OP wishes to match the scale of the two plots see: [(73522)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73522/121)

Comment: One brief comment that doesn't quite merit an edit. `dirs` with a list of two numbers specify the direction of the x-axis. I'll aim to edit my answer to meet the concept of Affine transformation (the concept, not the built-in function) tomorrow to cover the question "I have a given translation + rotation, what parameters I need to pass to `Inset`?". ps - upon writing, not so brief, after all.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example. You have to be careful with the plot range so that the aspect ratio is just right, otherwise the figure is going to look skewed.

```
transform = Composition[
   TranslationTransform[{10, 5}],
   RotationTransform[45 Degree]
   ];

ListLinePlot[{
  Table[transform@{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}],
  Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]
  },
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 20}, {-5, 20}},
 Axes -> None,
 Prolog -> {
   Arrowheads[{-Automatic, Automatic}],
   Arrow[{{0, 2 Pi}, {0, 0}, {2 Pi, 0}}],
   Arrow[transform /@ {{0, 2 Pi}, {0, 0}, {2 Pi, 0}}]
   }]
```

[image: Transformed functions]