# Is it possible to use non-orthogonal 2D axes for plots in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics, coordinate-transformation

I want to plot uni-variate functions using 2D plots but I want to be able to change the angle between the axes so that they are not perpendicular. Is this possible?

I have looked through all the graphics options and have not be able to discover any that accomplish this. Such an option might reasonably be called `AxesAngle`. I know I could do a plot without the axes and then draw these later on my own but this is not what I want. I want the plot to be based on non-parallel axes.

Comment: I'd start with reading https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html, assuming you have a recent-ish version.

Comment: Please post a minimal example.

Comment: The only example I know that uses non orthogonal axes are spacetime diagrams with Lorentz transformations of the axes. This what I found searching for that: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230857/how-to-draw-tilted-axes-for-spacetime-diagrams (for this next one maybe check the source code if you can) https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SpacetimeDiagram/ a github page but I did not check the notebook : https://github.com/bshoshany/spacetime-diagrams. If you do find something that fits your needs I would personally be curious to see how it works. It could be neat.

Answer (score 5):

You can rotate to achieve any desired angle between axes and also their position.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0, Sin[x]}, {x, -π, π}, 
 Axes -> {True, False, True}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

[image]