# How can I rotate the x and y axis?

Tags: rotation

I would like to know if it is possible to carry out a rotation involving the x and y axis (the gridline too) cause I know how to do it with a vector and an arrow but not with the axis.

Comment: If you want  a rotated object for visualization that is not a graphics object `Rotate[Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}], 45 Degree]`

Comment: If you want an image : `Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}] // Image // ImageRotate[#, 45 Degree] &`

Comment: If you want a graphics object then maybe you would need to construct the plot as a graphics object first. see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132568/extract-ticks-from-plot) for how to extract the ticks. For the curve you can use `Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}] //Cases[#,_Line,All] &`

Comment: You can also make a graphics Object from the image with errors using `ImageGraphics`

Comment: Consider as well the 3D graphics solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/276272/86543)

Comment: Please post a draft to illustrate the meaning of `rotate the x,y and gridlines`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to get rotated axes:

- Using the fifth argument of [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html):

  ```
  Graphics[
   Inset[Graphics[{}, Axes -> True], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {2, 2}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}],
   PlotRange -> 1
  ]
  ```

  [image]

  This will shear everything inside the inner `Graphics` expression. As you can see, even the labels of the axes are sheared.
- Using [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html) (new in 12.3):

  ```
  Graphics[
   {AxisObject[Line@{{-1, -1}/Sqrt[2], {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}], 
    AxisObject[Line@{{0, -1}, {0, 1}}]},
   PlotRange -> 1
  ]
  ```

  [image]

  Here, you can directly specify from where to where the axes should point. Only the direction of the axes is affected. As you can see, labels of the axes are not affected.

Comment: Thank you, your comment has been very useful to me. Just one more thing, is this possible tu with manipulate so you can rotate the axis like that???

Comment: With the `AxisObject` approach, you should be able to add interactivity just as if you had a normal line, e.g. `Manipulate[Graphics[{AxisObject[Line@{{0, 0}, Dynamic@p}]}, PlotRange -> 1], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]`