# How to guarantee the point's position is fixed in the Graphics and Image

Tags: graphics, image-processing, coordinate-transformation

```
SeedRandom[8]
plot = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@BezierFunction[temPoint = RandomReal[{-50, 50}, {5, 2}]][
    t], {t, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can hightlight a random point in this graphics.

```
SeedRandom[3]
Show[plot, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
   Point[randomPoint = 
     RandomReal /@ RegionBounds@DiscretizeGraphics[plot]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can change the `plot` to image.

```
Image[plot]
```

Then its coordinate system will be a [image coordinate system](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html#1708646374).To guarantee the `randomPoint` be the original graphics' position in the new coordinate system,I use `RescalingTransform` try to implement this target.

```
HighlightImage[
 Image[plot], {Red, PointSize[.03], 
  Point[RescalingTransform[
     First@Values[AbsoluteOptions[plot, PlotRange]], 
     Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions@Image[plot]}]]@randomPoint]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But as you see,there is a error in this method obviously.

Comment: These seem related in concept if not application: [(18034)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18034/121), [(73522)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73522/121), [(83636)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83636/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wow,Thanks for your links.I'll learn that one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't elegant, but I think it should work pretty reliably.

Start with the base plot:

```
plot = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@BezierFunction[temPoint = RandomReal[{-50, 50}, {5, 2}]][
    t], {t, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Create a version that has the point, but wrap the point in `Annotation`, with type `"Region"`:

```
plot2 = Show[plot, 
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
    Annotation[
     Point[randomPoint = 
       RandomReal /@ RegionBounds@DiscretizeGraphics[plot]], "Point", 
     "Region"]}]
```

Rasterize the second one, and extract the regions, converting to the center of the point:

```
{px, py} = Mean[{"Point", "Region"} /. Rasterize[plot2, "Regions"]];
```

Convert the main plot to an image:

```
image = Image[plot];
```

Get the dimensions of the image:

```
{ix, iy} = ImageDimensions[image];
```

Highlight the image, keeping in mind that the region annotations use a coordinate system that is flipped vertically from the usual one used by `Image`:

```
HighlightImage[
 Image[plot], {Red, PointSize[.03], Point[{px, iy - py}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.It's a surprise to me about the `Rasterize` can do this.Just a little suggestion for `Point[{px, iy - py}]` should be `Point[{px-0.5, iy - py-0.5}]` or I miss something.