# How to scale inset such that it takes up the specific region of a plot

Tags: graphics

Consider two plots, one of which will contain the other as an inset.

```
 inset = Plot[ x, {x, 1, 2}
  , Frame -> True
 ]
 A = Plot[ x^2 , {x, 1, 2} 
   , Epilog -> { Inset[ inset,  {1.5, 2.5},  {1, 1}, 0.5]}
 ]
```

This code works perfectly with one limitation. Let's say I want to place the inset that spans from 1.5 to 1.9 in the scale of x-axis in the main panel while keeping the aspect ratio of the inset constant. To achieve this effect, I had to manually controls the fourth option, which scales the inset object. Is there anyway to automate this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How to make Inset graphics maintain relative sizes when combined](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73522/121) the sizing itself is easy if we rasterize the inset plot:

```
Manipulate[
 p1 = Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, Frame -> True] // Rasterize;
 p2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 1, lim}, GridLines -> {{1.5, 1.9}}];
 size = (1.9 - 1.5)/(#2 - #) & @@ PlotRange[p2][[1]];
 Show[p2, Epilog -> {Inset[p1, {1.5, 2.5}, {0, 0}, Scaled[size]]}],
 {lim, 2, 5}
]
```

[image]

However dealing the the resizing of the non-rasterized `Graphics` is tricky. How should the tick labels outside the plot range be handled?

Using LLlAMnYP's functions from [How to align coordinate systems of Inset and enclosing Graphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83636/how-to-align-coordinate-systems-of-inset-and-enclosing-graphics/83659#83659) we could write:

```
Manipulate[
 p1 = Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, Frame -> True];
 p2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 1, lim}, GridLines -> {{1.5, 1.9}}];
 size = printerPointsPlotRange[p2][[1]]/realPlotRange[p2][[1]]*(0.4);
 Show[p2, Epilog -> {Inset[Show[p1, ImageSize -> size], {1.5, 2.5}, {Left, Bottom}, 
     Automatic]}],
 {lim, 2, 5}
]
```

[image]

This fits the inset including its tick labels neatly between the grid lines.