# How to show a smaller plot inside a bigger one?

Tags: plotting

I plot a function with `PlotRange -> All` called `pl1` and again plot the same but this time with `PlotRange -> a finite number` called `pl2`. Now I want to show `pl1` in large size and `pl2` inside it (exactly in top right of it or any arbitrary position) with a small size. A toy example can be

```
pl1 = Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
pl2 = Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 50]
```

How can I do it? I can use `GraphicsGrid` but I have no idea how to change the size and position of two graphics? `BaselinePosition` is useless without changing the sizes.

Note that in reality, I have plotted several functions in a single plot and I need to see the points where these functions intersect in a magnified plot (pl2).

Comment: `Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> Inset[ Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 50}], Scaled[{.4, .6}]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pl1 = Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
pl2 = Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 5}
  , GridLines -> Automatic
  , PlotRange -> 50
  , Background -> Nest[Lighter, Yellow, 3]]

pl3 = Plot[Exp[x]
  , {x, 0, 10}
  , PlotRange -> All
  , GridLines -> Automatic
  , Epilog -> {Inset[pl2, {2, 10000}, {0, 0}]}
  ]
```

Here (0,0) of the inset plot is aligned with (2,10000) in the main plot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. and how can I change the position of inner plot arbitrary? for example in the corner of top right?

Comment: Align it to a different point using the scheme shown. There is also a `Size` parameter in one of the syntax variations. Look at [138354](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138354/how-to-scale-inset-such-that-it-takes-up-the-specific-region-of-a-plot) as well.

Comment: There is a [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/InsetOneGraphicIntoAnother.html) as well in the docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help