# Parallel movement(Translation) of entire Graphics

Tags: graphics, functions, function-construction

Can we construct parallel movement function which act on `Graphics primitive` or `Graphics`?

Example of `Graphics primitive` : `Circle[{0,0},1]`

Example of `Graphics` : `Graphics[Circle[{0,0},1]]`

For example, can you construct function `F` or `G` ? (I want both)

[image]

The unit of parallel movement must be *user unit*.
I mean the radius length of `Circle[{0,0},1]` is 1 *user unit*.

Hope the function (`F` or `G`) do not rely on `Inset`.
It's too difficult to handle `Inset` accurately with my skills,
so I want to avoid `Inset` as much as possible (for a while).

Also I hope the function should act correctly on complicated case, like nested structure of  `Graphics`/`Show`/`Inset`.

If there is no direct method, then we should be able to do followings :

1. extract every graphic primitives from nested structure of `Graphics`/`Show`/`Inset`
2. apply parallel movement for all those graphic primitives
3. combine processed graphic primitives

The code would be lengthy and difficult to make but it would be useful. Anyone who doesn't have that code or have no time but think there is no direct method, please leave it as comment. Thank you!

Comment: Have you explored `TranslationTransform`?

Comment: No,  it is new to me.

Comment: Thank you! I think the problem was solved for `graphics primitive`. Can`TranslationTransform` be applied easily for `graphics` of complicated structures?

Comment: Perhaps `GraphicsComplex` could handle the nested structure you have but I am not conversant with its use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F[t_] := Translate[#, t] &;
G[t_] := MapAt[F[t], {1}];


Graphics[{Circle[], Line[{{.5, 0}, {.5, 1}}], 
  F[{1, 0}]@{Circle[], Red, Line[{{.5, 0}, {.5, 1}}]}}]
```

[image]

```
Show[Graphics[{Circle[], Line[{{.5, 0}, {.5, 1}}]}], 
 G[{1, 0}] @ Graphics[{Circle[{1, 0}, 1], Red, Line[{{.5, 0}, {.5, 1}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so far everything works perfectly with this. For example it works OK with `Imagesize->1->50`. This is the orthodox method for combining graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
circle = Circle[{0, 0}, 1]
Graphics[{circle, TranslationTransform[{1, 0}][circle]}]
```

Comment: Thank you, you've succeeded to make such `F`. Can you also make such `G` ?

Comment: What is the difference between F and G?

Comment: Imagine a very complicated nested structure of `Graphics`/`Show`/`Inset`/... Anyway it is `Graphics` (the head is `Graphics`). Name it `G`. Can you do translation transformation by {1,0}, to `G` easily?

Comment: No I don't think it is possible because `TranslationTransform` and similar transformations are applied to graphics-primitives only.

Comment: But probably you may agree this can be done in other way. 
There may be built-in commands that act on the entire `Graphics`, or.. 
It may a bit difficult, but first analyzing the given graphic, then translating each graphic primitives.

Comment: You asked for an easy way !

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not complete, for example it does not work well with `Graphics` containing `Inset`. To be specific, the text used in `Inset` does not move along other `Graphics` primitives.

Anyway my trial is

```
trs[G_, {x_, y_}] := 
 Graphics@GeometricTransformation[#, {x, y}] &@
    GraphicsGroup@Delete[#, 0] &@G
```

where `G` is a `Graphics` and `{x,y}` is a coordinate of translation.

[image]

Hope other users improve this code, and post it.
Other codes are

```
{Graphics[Circle[]],
 trs[Graphics[{Red, Disk[], Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}], Blue, 
    Disk[{2, 2}]}], {2, -2}],
 trs[Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]], {0, -4}],
 trs[Graphics[{Pink, Disk[], {Blue, Disk[{1, 0}]}, 
    Disk[{2, 0}]}], {0, -6}]}

Show[Graphics[Circle[]],
 trs[Graphics[{Red, Disk[], Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}], Blue, 
    Disk[{2, 2}]}], {2, -2}],
 trs[Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]], {0, -4}],
 trs[Graphics[{Pink, Disk[], {Blue, Disk[{1, 0}]}, 
    Disk[{2, 0}]}], {0, -6}]]
```